# Why is philosophy the root of Wikipedia?

Tags: logic, knowledge

- Go to any English Wikipedia page.
- Click the first link (not in brackets, italics or in a box).
- Repeat n times.

**Why do you end up at the philosophy page 95% of the time?**

I expect it has to do with the nature of describing what something is, beginning with the premise that *whatever* is a part of a bigger body or collection of knowledge OR the relationship of "x is a subset or component of y" (with **of** being the key word). I am tempted to view this as something analogous to how a dichotomous key works, but look forward to how someone knowledgeable in the field would explain it.

I would appreciate a succinct answer that explains the reason(s) why in both a philosophical context, and also for people not well versed in formal philosophical study. Given I fall into the latter group, I will be heavily weighting the votes for answers (and comments) in choosing a best answer.  I would also be interested in other examples of similar phenomena (like how [20Q](http://www.20q.net/) works), but this may be a separate question.

Note:  As my downvoter points out, this may not hold true for all languages, but it does work for any page in English.

Final Note:  Sad comment that a real life question about philosophy is closed. All of you who voted to close this... do you really not see a question here?  Any advice for improving this question to open it back up and at least allow another answer to evolve? If not, message sent I guess.  To me constructive means there is a reason, purpose or application for the question or answer.  There is a reason why I ask this question beyond mere curiosity.

Interestingly, here are some [examples](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18665/wikipedia-philosophy) of the code to document your trip from a topic you choose to end up at philosophy.

Comment: I checked, this is not true for every language, hence it can easily be considered a coincidence. By the way, if the _philosophy_ page has this property, _reality_ has it as well, then _being_, and _objective_.

Comment: OK.  So you checked and it doesn't work in another language.  Why not suggest I revise to question to add "in english" rather than immediately downvote the question due to a minor inaccuracy explaining a completely verifiable phenomena.  Sigh.

Comment: I didn't downvote you for a minor inaccuracy. On SE, we like posts to be supported by facts. These aren't a fact, I doubt that it works for the English wiki. As I said, considering that it doesn't work in other languages anyway, this is most likely a coincidence.

Comment: Fact: It works for every page in English.  My simple question is why.  You are welcome to doubt it, but by admitting that, you have already prejudged that it isn't true.  There is no coincidence here.  The fact that it doesn't work in another language doesn't disprove the phenomena doesn't exist.

Comment: Doubting doesn't mean saying it _isn't true_. Can you add some reference that this actually is true and that this isn't a coincidence? You seem to be pretty sure.

Comment: The steps to reproduce 100% of the time are at the start of the question.  You can even use the random page function, and no matter how obscure the page, if you follow those steps, you are always lead to philosophy.

Comment: That is no evidence. I'm sorry, I tried to help improve this post by pointing out inaccuracies, but you don't seem to pick it up; instead you're being irritated. If you want to discuss this any further, please [come to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/cafe-philosophy).

Comment: This is only true for 94.52% of cases. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Getting_to_Philosophy). At any rate, I don't think this is much of a philosophy question - maybe some sort of data analysis or linguistics question.

Comment: For an example of something that doesn't lead to philosophy, see [waste management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waste_management), which goes to waste collection and then back.

Comment: Good link commando.  I tried with many pages and didn`t find one it didn`t work for.  I stand corrected that it`s only true 94.52% of the time.  You really don`t think this question fits the FAQ criteria for this site?

Comment: @Keelan I am neither looking for a debate, nor am I irritated.  I am simply curious as to why this phenomena exists, and thought the Philosophy SE would be the place to ask a question about why philosophy seems to be the parent organizational structure rather than knowledge or something similar.

Comment: [Come to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/cafe-philosophy) if you want to discuss this further.

Comment: I think I have explained myself adequately.  As I mentioned, I'm not looking to get into a sematics debate. If this isn't the place for this question, close it.  If not, I'm looking forward to reading alternative takes on this phenomenon.

Comment: About your recent edit: it's not really a "real-life question about philosophy", unless you concieve of capital-P "philosophy" as some ethereal force which directs people's behaviour to refer to the *topic of investigation which we call* philosophy. The fact that your question is only about Wikipedia in English, and that you don't accept the idea that it has anything to do with writing style of 'categorisation' (per Keelan in his answer), basically make it difficult to tell just what you're looking for, or why it's a philosophical question; and you refuse to explain further. Not much we can do

Comment: Keelan's answer is that it's a coincidence.  A writing style based on 'categorization' is not a coincidence.  That absolutely could be the sole cause.  I stand by the intent of my edit fully.  Not sure how you translate "Any advice for improving this question to open it back up and at least allow another answer to evolve?" into "refuse to explain further". I didn't claim it was a philosophical question, but it is about Philosophy and why it might be at the top of their hierarchical organization of information as opposed to... say "knowledge".

Comment: isn't a useful question to ask why a mountain exists (for what purpose); it is just a fact that mountains do exist. The more useful question is asking why mountains get formed, in which geology has answers. You've been pointed out answers as to why philosophy become the root of Wikipedia; the other question of why is a meaningless question.

Comment: If I wanted to know about how a mountain forms, I would ask for the input of someone learned in the study of geology.  Despite opposition, I still maintain that someone with expertise in the field might yield some insight.  

The one answer provided points out nothing more than his judgement that it's a coincidence, and references theories and allusion. There is some comprehensive description of the phenomenon, but not a comprehensive answer.

Comment: To put things in perspective, take an average question on this site and pose it to the average person on the street.  They would likely ask you the purpose of your meaningless question.  Does it matter whether or not they understand the meaning/relevance of the question, or are you more interested in what their answer might be?

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in the comments, this can easily be a coincidence. This doesn't work for all languages (example: http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taal) and commando points out in the comments that it doesn't work for the English wiki either ([official reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aGetting_to_Philosophy)); only in 94% of the cases. An example is [Waste management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waste_management), which goes to Waste collection and back.

The question arises: what about the pages *Philosophy* links to? The route is as follows:

- Reality
- Being
- Objectivity (philosophy)
- Philosophy

So *if* the philosophy page would've had this property, three others would have it as well.

However, 94% is still pretty good. To explain this phenomenon, let's have a look at a [random page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Malina):

> Joshua Charles Malina (pron.: [/mɛˈlinæ/](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aIPA_for_English#Key); born January 17, 1966) is an [American](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States) [film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film) and [stage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stage_%28theatre%29) [actor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor).

As you can see, when we're describing something, we're putting it in categories, as Aristotle said. We put Joshua Charles Malina in the category of Americans, that of film actors and that of stage actors.

When we look at the following page, we'll see something similar for the USA and we go the *federal republic*. Then again, to *federation*. To *union* is a categorizing again. The reference to *state* has the same pattern, and so we go further and further, categorizing and categorizing, making the subject broader and broader, and then finally we come at the subject which can be applied to everything and which was the root of any scientific method: philosophy.

The key to this popularly suspected behaviour of Wikipedia is that the first sentence most of the time is a categorizing statement.

You can find more speculations on [Getting to Philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aGetting_to_Philosophy). They give the same explanation as I did:

> There have been some theories on this phenomenon, with the most prevalent being the tendency for Wikipedia pages to move up a "classification chain." According to this theory, the Wikipedia Manual of Style guidelines on how to write the lead section of an article recommend that the article should start by defining the topic of the article, so that the first link of each page will naturally take the reader into a broader subject, eventually ending in wide-reaching pages such as Mathematics, Science, Language, and of course, Philosophy, nicknamed the "mother of all sciences".

Comment: I disagree with your use of the word coincidence, and would think someone studying philosophy would be as open to exploring proof of something, rather than making assumptions when definite proof is available.  I do agree with your last sentence and perhaps there is linguistic tendency or norm to start explanations with categorical statements that doesn't exist in some other languages... but I fail to understand what you even mean is a coincidence.

Comment: @Dallas "when definite proof is available" - we just got a reference that this isn't true: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Getting_to_Philosophy - oops... A coincidence is something that just happens to be so but doesn't need to have a system or reason behind it.

Comment: You are arguing semantics here.  There is definite proof that this phenomena occurs more than 90% of the time.  My question is simply why it exists. Please note that I am not downvoting you immediately because I disagree or because you are making assumptions.  I am truly curious if someone with expertise in the area could shed some light on reasons.

Comment: But @Dallas, I didn't make assumptions. I only speculated. I tried to give a possible explanation in the third paragraph (from "However, 94% is still pretty good."). I also linked to more speculations on wikipedia itself. Regarding this, I consider my answer to be a valid answer to your question. All answers will be speculating as there cannot be given one, absolutely true, reason.

Comment: You literally made two assumptions using the word assuming itself, if you reread your original answer.  The fact remains that there is a phenomena, it does exist, I believe it does fit into the site mandate for content, and I look forward to hearing alternative explanations.

Comment: @Dallas let's discuss the current answer, shall we?

Comment: No offense, but I am headed to bed.  I wish you were willing to discuss modifying/improving the question rather than defending your point of view/answer.

Comment: @Dallas I'm sorry you feel that way. As I said before, I tried to improve your question by pointing out inaccuracies. If you want to discuss this further, [come to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/cafe-philosophy) - ping me if I'm not there. No offense taken and goodnight.